# Is it appropriate to ask for the state-of-the-art on a specific problem?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

**Is it on-topic to ask for the latest works on a particular problem, if the problem is specific enough?**

E.g. 'what are the latest works on graph theory' would obviously not be OK, but what about 'what are the latest works on fast nearly-balanced binary space partitioning algorithms'?

On one hand this will (hopefully) constantly change, but on the other if the problem is narrowly enough defined, there should be an objectively correct answer at any given time.

What if the question is marked as a community-wiki?

(I would like to know if its OK to ask for the current best practical algorithm to perform a minimal relaxation ordinal embedding to a line.)

Comment: I think that this kind of question would likely be "too broad", so it would need care to keep it very narrow. It would also be important to include enough context to explain what you already know - just asking "What is the state of the art about ...?"  would not be a very good post.

Comment: Separately, the question you mentioned  asking about the particular current best practical algorithm would probably be a better fit for a different SE site. That sort of practical CS question is not really a good fit here.

Comment: Also, don't think of Community Wiki as allowing a lesser-quality question. There are some questions here that are soft and community wiki, but (usually) they are still good questions.